# React Native Firebase Facebook login works, but is not authenticated after successful log in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, react-native-firebase

I have implemented facebook authentication via react-native-firebase. When the user logs in the user shows up as authenticated with facebook in the dashboard which is great.

My problem is, I cant use firebase.auth().currentUser to get the signed in user like I was able to do with email and password authentication.

The user shows up as null and I am not able to write to my database (even though it says I have successfully signed in).

Here is what my function looks like to handle the login:

```
  onLoginFacebook = () => {
    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(result => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('cancelled');
        }
        console.log(
          `login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`,
        );
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const credential = RNFirebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
          data.accessToken,
        );
        return RNFirebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
      })
      .then(currentFBUser => {
        console.log(`Facebook Login with user: ${JSON.stringify(currentFBUser)}`);
        //NOT WORKING 
        const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
        const uid = currentUser.uid;
        //NOT WORKING
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authedUser => {
          if (authedUser) {
            Actions.home();
          } else {
            Actions.checkAuth();
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Login failed with ${error}`);
      });
  };
```

I appreciate all the help I can get with this issue, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is what ive done to implement facebook login , in my react native app, im sharing the code below,

```
import { AccessToken, LoginManager } from "react-native-fbsdk";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import axios from "axios";
import { api } from "../config/api";
import { getToken } from './auth';
import {setData} from '../modules/localCache';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

// Calling the following function will open the FB login dialogue:
export async function facebookLogin() {

  try {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      "public_profile",
      "email",
    ]);

    if (result.isCancelled) {
      // handle this however suites the flow of your app
      throw new Error("User cancelled request");
    }



    // get the access token
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
      // handle this however suites the flow of your app
      throw new Error("Something went wrong obtaining the users access token");
    }

    // create a new firebase credential with the token
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      data.accessToken,
    );

    //firebase token --> await firebase.getToken();


    // login with credential
    const firebaseUserCredential = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential);

    // console.warn(JSON.stringify(firebaseUserCredential.user.toJSON()));

    let responseData = await firebaseUserCredential.user.toJSON();
```

here i was getting the responseData with the creds like email and facebook id. Hope it helps .

Feel free for doubts. Will help you regarding it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to fix it somehow! Now my issue is deleting the user, to re-authenticate prior to deleting should I be using the same approach?